# Installing CocoaPods: no response

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

Trying to install CocoaPods from the terminal:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

After entering my root password, nothing happens.

How can I debug that?

Comment: Sounds like you should check out RVM or rbenv for managing Ruby stuff. The Ruby support that ships with OS X seems quite slow with stuff like that.

Comment: That was indeed very slow, but finally worked.

Answer (score 434, accepted):

For others wondering the same, installing the gem takes forever. If you run:

```
export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

gem install cocoapods -V
```

Installing with flag `V` enables verbose output which will let you see all the output as it is going through the download and install, it's quite a lot.

Comment: Also, updating the package manager seems to speed things up alot. `sudo gem update --system`

Comment: Just a note for **-V** (it is in uppercase) :D

Comment: instead of **-V** you can use **--verbose**

Comment: This verbose option should be on by default... I aborted the install three times before I found this post :~

Comment: @NicolasMiari If you are used to a *Nix OS you would not be complaining :)

Comment: Great answer. I would have never figured out it was working otherwise. Just curious. Anyone know why its so full of 302 redirects?

Comment: Thanks.  I had also given up, and kept quitting, as nothing appeared.  Remind me again, what year is this...?

Answer (score 55):

update gem to the newest release using

`sudo gem update --system` and it should work a bit faster

Answer (score 32):

I had to wait at least 5 minutes before:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

Appears

Answer (score 10):

It's not stuck, it's downloading file for ruby from the internet. you can check this by following below steps:

1. Open ***Activity Monitor***
2. Select ***Network*** option
3. Check below Google Chrome. (***ruby*** ***downloading***)

[image]

Comment: It is true that `ruby` is downloading cocoapods slowly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it takes forever keep calm and wait for at least 5 minutes , then you will see something, I did that in Ventura 13, I had to wait for 10 minutes. Hope this is helps, its like "light at the end of the tunnel".

Answer (score 2):

You should do it in two separated commands:

First:

```
gem update
```

Then:

```
export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 2):

MacOS Sonoma 14.0, installing `cocoapods` for `flutter doctor` check.

I have **cocoapods** installed by this way:

**Step 1** (install HomeBrew)

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)
```

**Step 2** (Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH)

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/”YOUR USER FORLDER”/.zprofile  
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

**Step 3** (now you can install cocoapods)

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: Just do this instead of using gem. Way better and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I received an error:
"Error installing cocoapods:
The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.3. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.3` and then running the current command again
activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210."

So, I had to run 'sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.3', for Ventura 13

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing latest Git version from

https://git-scm.com/downloads

This worked for me

Write the following commands in Terminal:

1. `export GEM_HOME=~/.gems`
2. `export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH`
3. `gem install cocoapods`
4. Set the path of the project with the command `cd path/to/project`
5. `pod init`
6. Open podfile
7. Add appropriate pod
8. `pod install`