# Get stuck at installation of Cocoapod

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to install cocoapod on my mac .When I enter the setup command "`sudo gem install cocoapods -V`" it process and then get stuck at these line

```
Successfully installed escape-0.0.4
Installing gem cocoapods-0.39.0
Downloading gem cocoapods-0.39.0.gem
GET https://ruby.taobao.org/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0.gem
```

I let it go for about 2 hours but nothing happening and also nothing downloads anymore. What should I do?

Comment: try `sudo gem install cocoapods` again

Comment: @Warif Akhand Rishi actually , I have run it with sudo

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using?

Comment: Is the URL blocked in your environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your gems

> sudo gem update

then

> sudo gem install cocoapods

it might help :)

Comment: Try this solution at last, because "sudo gem update" takes too much time. Do it only if you are sure that there is not any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with super user command `sudo gem install cocoapods`

or

update gem to the newest release using

```
sudo gem update
```

follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355165/xcode-installing-cocoapods-no-response)

Comment: actually , I have run it with sudo