# Pod install displaying error in cocoapods version 1.0.0.beta.1

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My podfile was working but after updating to cocoapods version 1.0.0.beta.1

pod install displays following error

```
MacBook-Pro:iOS-TuneIn home$ pod install
Fully deintegrating due to major version update
Deleted 1 'Copy Pods Resources' build phases.
Deleted 1 'Check Pods Manifest.lock' build phases.
Deleted 1 'Embed Pods Frameworks' build phases.
- libPods.a
- Pods.debug.xcconfig
- Pods.release.xcconfig
Deleted 1 'Copy Pods Resources' build phases.
Deleted 1 'Check Pods Manifest.lock' build phases.
- libPods.a
Deleted 1 'Copy Pods Resources' build phases.
Deleted 1 'Check Pods Manifest.lock' build phases.
- libPods.a
Deleted 1 'Copy Pods Resources' build phases.
Deleted 1 'Check Pods Manifest.lock' build phases.
- libPods.a
Deleted 1 'Copy Pods Resources' build phases.
Deleted 1 'Check Pods Manifest.lock' build phases.
- libPods.a
- libPods.a
Deleted 1 empty `Pods` groups from project.
Removing `Pods` directory.

Project has been deintegrated. No traces of CocoaPods left in project.
Note: The workspace referencing the Pods project still remains.
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The dependency `AFNetworking (= 2.6.3)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `MBProgressHUD (~> 0.9.1)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `PDKeychainBindingsController (~> 0.0.1)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `FMDB/SQLCipher` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `ZXingObjC (~> 3.1.0)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `SDWebImage (~> 3.7.2)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `SignalR-ObjC (~> 2.0.0.beta3)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `CJPAdController (from `https://github.com/nabeelarif100/CJPAdController.git`)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `ECSlidingViewController (~> 2.0.3)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `VGParallaxHeader` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `EMString` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `Google/SignIn` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `VIPhotoView (~> 0.1)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `EncryptedCoreData (from `https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data.git`)` is not used in any concrete target.
MacBook-Pro:iOS-TuneIn home$
```

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.3'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
pod 'PDKeychainBindingsController', '~> 0.0.1'
pod 'FMDB/SQLCipher'
pod 'ZXingObjC', '~> 3.1.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7.2'
pod 'SignalR-ObjC','~>2.0.0.beta3'
pod 'CJPAdController', :git => 'https://github.com/nabeelarif100/CJPAdController.git'
pod 'ECSlidingViewController', '~> 2.0.3'
pod 'VGParallaxHeader'
pod 'EMString'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'VIPhotoView', '~> 0.1'
pod 'EncryptedCoreData', :git => 'https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data.git'
```

Answer (score 498, accepted):

You have to specify a target for each pod.

e.g. if before you had your Podfile written like this:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1.4'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.2'
```

just change it to

```
target "TargetName" do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1.4'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.2'
end
```

Comment: That worked. And for adding same pods to multiple targets refer to http://natashatherobot.com/cocoapods-installing-same-pod-multiple-targets/

Comment: being the target the workspace  name?  eg. `"TargetName"`

Comment: Target being the target name :)

Comment: Thanks It's working now, but the strange thing is (Specifying a target was not required in my earlier Xcode projects)!

Answer (score 57):

After the new changes to cocoapods, You have to add the following lines to your podfile.

```
target "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME" do

     pod "YOUR_POD"

end
```

Comment: you should deserve more votes @Karthik. anyone didn't mention what is the "target" means here

Comment: Thank you @JanakaRRajapaksha

Answer (score 19):

From the CocoaPods website:

> CocoaPods provides a `pod init` command to create a Podfile with smart defaults. You should use it.

Comment: it din't add the `target 'name' do end`

Answer (score 9):

you must add `target 'your target' do` and `end` around you pod like below.

```
target 'your target' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.3'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
pod 'PDKeychainBindingsController', '~> 0.0.1'
end
```

plus: You may be need remove the pods dir, Podfile.lock and xcworkspace file, run the `pod install` again.

Comment: I also needed to delete the Podfile.lock and other files.  When I just added target 'your target' do and end, the installation succeeded but did not update the file version - just reinstalled the previous version.  After deleting the Podfile.lock and other files, the most updated files were installed.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue today. For mitigation, I unintall cocoapod, then install again version 0.39.

here is the link how to uninstall: https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine

This answer does not fix the root cause, but can get you unblocked. I don't have enough reputation to leave comments, so I put an answer here to unblock you.

Comment: A good reference but you should have also mentioned the steps just in case the reference is taken down some day.

Answer (score 2):

I was this operation in the podfile：

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

target "targetprojectname" do

pod "AFNetworking"

end

Comment: This is exact answer. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

My podfile was formatted correctly, so the answer did not work for me.  What I **had** to do was all of the following:
First,

1. gem uninstall cocoapods
2. rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
3. rvm use ruby-2.1.2
4. rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
5. rvm rubygems latest
6. sudo gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
7. sudo gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
8. gem install cocoapods -v 1.0.0.beta.1 --pre -V

I had SSL errors, timeout errors, and path errors.  This fixed all of these.  I am adding this answer in hopes that it will help someone - most people with this issue will NOT need to go through all of these steps, and should not do so if it is not neccesary.  Keep in mind, that this is changing the d/l link to not use https, so be sure to change it back once you have resolved this issue.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612185/unable-to-install-cocoapods-gem-from-rubygems-org-bad-response-backend-read-e), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o?rq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355165/xcode-installing-cocoapods-no-response) Stack Overflow question helped me finally resolve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and even I changed to

target "TargetName" do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1.4'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.2'
end

It seems has some cache problem, it always read old version of PodFile, even I remove PodFile, the same error show up. It's weird.

However, when I open a new terminal , running pod install, it works.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add and Open ***Podfile*** in Xcode instead of TextEdit or any other editor. (*Syntax highlighting while viewing a pod file will simplify the process of finding syntax errors*)

2) Add project dependancies as follows in your ***Podfile***

```
def pods
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
  pod 'ORStackView', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
end
```

3) Add above define ***pods*** in ***project target*** as follows

```
target 'App_Target_Name' do
  pods
end
```

Answer (score 0):

for New version of cocoapods i.i 1.0.1

pod 'SlideMenuControllerSwift'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'SearchTextField'

I was getting error:

The dependency `SlideMenuControllerSwift` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `SDWebImage` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `SearchTextField` is not used in any concrete target.

than i changed it to

target "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME" do

```
 pod "YOUR_POD"
```

end

than it worked

Answer (score 0):

Pod file is just a ruby file, you need to specify required pod for all target.
one of the available solution is to define all required pods in shared_pos, and use that for each target.

For ex:

## Podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

def Shared_Pods
    pod 'Quick', '0.5.0'
    pod 'Nimble', '2.0.0-rc.1'
end

target 'MyMainTarget' do
    Shared_Pods
end

target 'MyUITests' do
    Shared_Pods
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'YourTargetName' do

  ALL PODS HERE

end
```

open terminal, go to project folder and enter code

```
pod update
```