# What is a "target" in Cocoapods?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I was figuring out how to use Cocoapods and I found this: [Pod install displaying error in cocoapods version 1.0.0.beta.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556991/pod-install-displaying-error-in-cocoapods-version-1-0-0-beta-1)

It says I have to write the following line: `target "TargetName" do` followed by some things. But I am confused about what is my "TargetName".

For example, what would be the target name in this project:

[image]

Or, where can I find my project's "target"? I am using the latest version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the targets like this:

Click on the `SnapKit Tutorial.xcodeproj` file:

[image]

Then click on the button in the top left:

[image]

After that, a tab will appear that will show the names of the targets:
[image]

Comment: in my case Pods behaved weirdly (in some cases even refusing to compile the project) when I had spaces in the name. Can anyone confirm?