# Cocoapods dependency format

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am getting an issue with Cocoapods. Please, find detailed explanation below,

Initially my cocoapods was like this,

### Podfile

> pod 'Fabric'
>
> pod 'Crashlytics'
>
> pod "VKVideoPlayer", "~> 0.1.1"

Then, my app needs GA (Google Analytics) so, i have added

> pod 'Google/Analytics'

into my `Podfile` it gives following errors

> Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.
>
> Analyzing dependencies [!] The dependency Fabric (~> 3.4) is not used in any concrete target.

And, i found a question which related to this issue and found out an answer too [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558516/940096)

Afterwards, my cocoapod file looks like this,

> target 'MyApp' do
>
> pod 'Fabric'
>
> pod 'Crashlytics'
>
> pod "VKVideoPlayer", "~> 0.1.1"
>
> pod 'Google/Analytics'
>
> end

It works fine. But, i am facing an issue when i try to create a `IBOutlet` reference to my `VKVideoPlayer` I am getting following issue?

> 2017-03-10 12:36:01.323549 MyApp[1367:555515] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:48): Uncaught exception: [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key orientationLock.
>   2017-03-10 12:36:01.375647 MyApp[1367:555515] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
>   2017-03-10 12:36:06.345638 MyApp[1367:555515]*  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key orientationLock.'
>   * First throw call stack:
>   (0x182c251b8 0x18165c55c 0x182c24e80 0x1836598f0 0x188ddc11c 0x188fddaf8 0x182b44034 0x188fdc4cc 0x188fde768 0x10043d720 0x10043f598 0x100448850 0x188ada924 0x188ada4ec 0x1000c9550 0x1000cb138 0x1001d1e50 0x102121258 0x102121218 0x102126280 0x182bd2810 0x182bd03fc 0x182afe2b8 0x1845b2198 0x188b457fc 0x188b40534 0x1001a4c1c 0x181ae15b8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Kindly, help me for this.

Comment: Maybe you need to give the class name in the Identity Inspector!

Comment: @AnuragSharma Class name already given.

Comment: Is your viewController has the correctly named class in the Identity Inspector! Or one possible reason is when copying & pasting elements from one controller into another, Xcode somehow keeps that link to the original controller, even after editing & relinking this element into the new controller

Comment: is the problem in Analytics  change the dependency from `pod 'Google/Analytics'` to pod 'Google/Analytics'``"~> 3.0"`

Comment: or else raise the ticket to google

Answer (score -1):

Please try GoogleAnalytics 3.13, I have also same problem but after that  i am try to older version than it will fine for me, because some problem in new version.

Comment: Let me try the same. And tell you

Comment: Problem is not with GoogleAnalytics bro. I guess its all about path of the pods.

Comment: You are getting same problem

Comment: Yes i am getting the same problem

Comment: Please try one more time but this time add GoogleAnalytics library without using pod.